# Check error polyline in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, plugins

I am working with topology checker in QGIS 2.18 to check error overshoot, undershoot , but it show all error, so I got many difficult in fix error. 
Is there any tool the same with topology checker to check error in QGIS?

Answer (score 1):

Use the Geometry checker (Vector > Geometry checker) and select the **Line must not have dangles** option.

More information about how to use the Geometry checker tool in here:

https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/core_plugins/plugins_geometry_checker.html

Comment: I got it, thanks so much